# AnyLogic GIS regions acting as agents

Tags: gis, anylogic, agent

I want to have different GIS regions as agents to see their interaction with each other and later on create more agents inside each of them and make them interact too.
How do I convert regions to agents?
And also some regions when I find them on map and click "turn into gis points/regions" they create multiple points with same name just 1,2,3, etc in the ending instead of only one combined. How to fix that? Newbie friendly please

Answer (score 0):

> How do I convert regions to agents?

You don't. Instead, you create a normal agent type ("MyGISRegion") and provide it a parameter `p_MyRegion` of type `GISRegion`. For every region you create, you also now instantiate such an agent and set its parameter to the region created.

If you are not familiar with parameters and agent types and instantiating agents, do check the step-by-step tutorials in the AL help :)

PS: Welcome to SOF and AnyLogic. On SOF, you only ask 1 question, so please open a separate question for your other problem. See some guidance [here](https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/11/12/an-introduction-to-the-anylogic-community) and [here](https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow).